# Triple joined path - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

So I'm having a `path` in `Photoshop` and I'm using it for drawing, however I would like to have my line have additional lines added to it, which aint going to fit together with other lines. Is this possible and how?

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to group them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You Can't**.

Anchor points have an "in" and an "out" and that's it. You can not have 3 paths connected to *any* single anchor point.

Comment: +1 to Scott’s comment. Depending on your requirements, there are other strategies that can work. Often, non-joined lines will be just fine, even if you need a stroke or fill that looks like it is one object.